# Select MIN and MAX temperature in last 24 hours and last 30 days

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, pivot, min

I have a mysql database for data logger. I would like to find minimum and maximum values(temperature) in last 24 hours and in last 30 days. I dont realy have experience with Mysql and php. I tried this, but does't work.

```
$min_value = "
    SELECT * 
    FROM datalogger 
    ORDER BY id 
    LIMIT 24 (SELECT *
                FROM datalogger 
                WHERE temperature = ( SELECT MIN(temperature) FROM datalogger ))";
```

Thanks

Comment: We do not have a [mcve] here.  Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation. Assuming that the measure date is stored in column `ts`, you would phrase this as:

```
select 
    min(case when ts > now() - interval 1 day then temperature end) min_last_24h,
    min(ts) min_last_30_day
from datalogger
where ts > now() - interval 30 day
```

This generates a resultset made of one row and two columns, with the minimum temperature over the two different date ranges.

If you want this in two different rows, then an approach is:

```
select x.when, min(temperature) min_temperature
from datalogger d
inner join (
    select 'last 1 day' when, 1 d
    union all select 'last 30 day', 30
) x on d.ts > now() - interval x.d day
from datalogger
group by x.when
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two queries. One for the hourly min/max in the past day, and another for the daily min/max in the past 30 days.

```
$last_day = $conn->query('SELECT MIN(temperature) AS mintemp, MAX(temperature) AS maxtemp
    FROM datalogger
    WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY');
$row = $last_day->fetch_assoc();
echo "24 hours: Lowest temp = {$row['mintemp']}, highest temp = {$row['maxtemp']}<br>";

$last_month = $conn->query('SELECT MIN(temperature) AS mintemp, MAX(temperature) AS maxtemp
    FROM datalogger
    WHERE time > NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY');
$row = $last_day->fetch_assoc();
echo "30 days: Lowest temp = {$row['mintemp']}, highest temp = {$row['maxtemp']}<br>";
```

Comment: thanks. how can i make query fot this, to put the values in variable and "echo" them? thank you

Comment: The same way you echo the result of any other query.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to show the results in a table.

Comment: yes it works :) but i think that i didn't write clear what i want. and sorry to waste your time for this. So my data logger sends data about temperature hourly into mysql database. I want to find only 1 minimum value in last 24 hours, and only one minimum value in last 30 days. for example: the coldest hour in last 24 hours was: "2020-10-29 6:00 - 5,5 celsius. At the other side: the coldest hour in last 30 days was 2020-10-05 3:00 - 3.00 celsius. I want only one variable for coldest hour in 24 hours and one variable for last 30 days. for example $temp_min_24h   and $temp_min_30d. Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't bother with prepared statements when there are no parameters. The rogue quotes were just editing errors as I kept revising the queries.

Comment: Right you are -- no params. The formatting because of the extra `'` tricked my eye.  You might enterain using a `UNION` so that only 1 trip to the db is necessary (the resultset rows will have the same columns).

Comment: For this I don't think it's needed and this is much clearer.